# accessing folder with diacritisc in windows 7

Tags: windows, file, diacritics

I am unable to access, by double-clicking, a folder named "Fișiere recep.". That "ş" is a Romanian character.
I am not able to rename it either. Any idea on how to recover the files inside that folder?
Thank you very much, in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may have luck by attempting to access it through a command prompt using the `cd` command. If that doesn't work, then you can try booting into Linux from a removable drive and attempting to rename the folder from there.

Comment: cd doesn't work... booting into linux might, but haven't tried it - i don't think i have a blank CD - i guess i will use a stick

Comment: You don't have to use a CD if your computer's BIOS is modern enough to boot from USB (most likely it is). You can use [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) (which I recommend) with an empty and large enough drive for the same purpose.

Comment: hmm... cannot boot from usb stick, even if i select in boot options (F12 at booting), USB option... I've tried with usb legacy emulation enabled and disabled. Any idea...?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I used a hex disk editor.